# When to use Collections vs Directories?

Tags: marklogic

Need help trying to understand using collections vs directories.  All of the courses I've taken at MLU use collections.  After reading this link:  https://docs.marklogic.com/5.0/guide/app-dev/properties#id_86551, I'm still unclear why I would use directories over collections.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Directories are hierarchical, while collections can overlap arbitrarily. Directories are implicit whenever you use a `/` in the document URI, and they are not mutually exclusive of collections. A document belonging to a directory hierarchy can also be a member of multiple collections. For example:

```
cts:search(xdmp:directory('/path/to/documents/',
  cts:collection-query(('collection1', 'collection2)))
```

The above would search for any documents whose URIs are prefixed with that directory path (i.e. `/path/to/documents/doc1.xml`) that belong to at least one of those collections.

Under the hood collections are stored in a properties document/fragment that parallels the document. Changing a document's collections is similar to changing it's directory/path in the sense that you are performing a document update/overwrite anytime either is changed, so there's no particular performance benefit to using one over the other. Use what makes most sense when modeling and organizing your data.

Comment: note: the same word is used for 2 things in marklogic documentation  "directory".
As above is one meaning.  Another are "Directory Fragments" or"Directory Nodes" -- which is an actually (not virtual) document created in ML with the URI of a directory.   For the most part, explicit "Directory Nodes" are not needed, and *most of* the xxx:directory* apis refer to the former.
THe difference is that a Directory Node -- is an actual 'node' (document fragment) in the DB that you can write data to.   Its mostly used by the WEBDAV component.